# Add an image selection list to a content type

Tags: 7, nodes

I'd like to add an image selection to a content type, what would let the user chose
for instance an icon, from a predefined list, to attach to this content type.

Any suggestions on how i could achieve that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a way to do so Using Node reference field type, enabled by Drupal 6 CCK module or in Drupal 7 it's with: [Reference Module](http://drupal.org/project/references)

Once the module enabled, Node reference will be available as CCK field type :)

Comment: how did u do that? I have the same problem, I want select list list if image. but refrence module let me only choose node title not image!!!